# How can I extract specific parts of a string matching a specific regex in bash?

Tags: regex, bash

I'm working in bash, chosen mainly so I could get some practice with it, and I have a string that I know matches the regex `[:blank:]+([0-9]+)[:blank:]+([0-9]+)[:blank:]+$SOMETHING`, assuming I got that right. (Whitespace, digits, whitespace, digits, whitespace, some string I've previously defined.) By "matches," I mean it includes this format as a substring.

Is there a way to set the two strings of digits to specific variables with just one regex matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$BASH_REMATCH` contains the groups from the latest regex comparison done by `[[`.

```
$ [[ ' 123 456 ' =~ [[:blank:]]+([0-9]+)[[:blank:]]+([0-9]+)[[:blank:]]+ ]] && echo "*${BASH_REMATCH[1]}*${BASH_REMATCH[2]}*"
*123*456*
```

Comment: Let's try it!

>syntax error near unexpected token '('
>'$ [[ $SOURCE_STRING =~ [[:blank:]]+([0-9]+)[[:blank:]]+([0-9]+)[[:blank:]]+$SOMETHING ]]'

Comment: Are you *sure* you're using `bash` and `[[`?

Comment: Uh, yes? I can't see how I wouldn't be. The line I posted after the second > was the actual line in my script, I followed `bash` tutorials, the script starts with `#!/bin/bash`... what's left to say?

Comment: Then why is there a "$" there? In my example, that's the prompt.

Comment: It is there due to my misinterpretation of your example! Up and running now; thank you very much!