# How can I apply regex to a variable in Bash and assign what it matches to another variable?

Tags: regex, bash

Im trying to take a file's name and trim of the `.tar` and everything else that follows that. Basically, if theres a dot, capture everything before it. So if I have a file called "Something-some.tar.xz" how would I use regex in Bash code to capture "Something-some"? I've figured out that the regex for it is:

```
^([^.]+)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I extract specific parts of a string matching a specific regex in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371242/how-can-i-extract-specific-parts-of-a-string-matching-a-specific-regex-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex matching isn't necessary, if your goal is just to trim `.tar*` from the end of a string.  Bash has builtin string manipulation.  In your case, you can remove the trailing `.tar*` (`*` is a glob, not regex kleene star) using

```
var=/path/to/some/archive.tar; echo "${var%%.tar*}"
```

capturing the output in another variable if you like.

Comment: If you want to remove *any* extension (not just .tar), use `"${var%%.*}"`. However, there's a potential problem because this works on the entire string, not just the filename at the end, so if the var is "/path/to/project-v.1/subdir/archive.tar", it'll trim it all the way back to ""/path/to/project-v".

Comment: yea, the "everything else that follows" made me think that might be a problem

Comment: Alright, im trying to take a variable like-- m="something-some.tar.xz" -- then assign "something-some" to another variable.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks alot, didn't know it could be done that way! So im guessing that `%%` removes whatever comes after the indicated `variable`.

Comment: if your variable is like that either glob, `.tar*` or `.*` will work since `%%` matches the longest match from the end of the string, refer to https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html